# Do I need to "protect" low voltage cables that are run through an insulated wall?

Tags: insulation, wiring, code-compliance, cabling, speakers

I'm planning to run speaker cables from a new outlet at an uninsulated wall to a new outlet at an insulated wall.  I've already run Cat5e and coaxial cable to the uninsulated wall, and am comfortable with the process.  However I have a concern with the similar task of running cable through an insulated wall.

Other than installing a low-voltage box at the outlet, do I need to protect the cable that will snake through the wall/insulation in any way?  I have a concern that the cables and their slack will pose a fire hazard since they will either run through the insulation or between the insulation and drywall in an untidy fashion (i.e. not secured to joists/studs for new work).  Should I run the cables through a plastic tube/conduit for extra safety?

The speaker cable is CL2-rated, so perhaps my concern is unwarranted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your wall is closed up then you don't have to worry about it.  It looks like class 2 wire is rated to go into walls.  Only use wire that is rated to be in the walls for uses like what you have.  The only things to worry about with class 2 or class 3 wiring is:

1. Class 2/3 should never be used in the same electrical box (without a low voltage divider or in the same conduit with your house wiring.
2. Class 2/3 should be kept at least 10" away from house wiring. Try to run in a separate bay.
3. Remember when crossing house wiring with class 2/3 it should be at 90 degrees.

If your wall is open then if you can spare the money for ENT or smurf tube (bendable, corrugated, PVC that is usually blue) then that will give your wiring more protection.  It is sold in 10ft lengths or 100ft coils.  You can run low-voltage class 2/3 or regular house wiring, but not at the same time.  It will also give the transmission that is carried on the class 2/3 less interference when around house wiring.

[image: ENT - Electrical Non-Metallic Tubing]

Comment: Using tubing is also good for "future proofing".  If you ever have to replace the cable or run new cable, it's much easier if you have the tubing there already.

Answer (score 2):

CL-2 rated wire is fine to run in the walls without anything extra.  There is no need to put it in conduit or anything to protect it.